# Summing columns of a 2D tensor according to multiple sets of indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, I would like to sum columns of a 2D tensor according to multiple sets of indices.

For example:

Summing the columns of the following tensor

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [5 4 3 2 1]]
```

according to the 2 sets of indices (first set to sum columns 0 1 2 and second set to sum columns 3 4)

```
[[0,1,2],[3,4]]
```

should give 2 columns

```
[[6  9]
 [12 3]]
```

Remarks:

1. All columns' indices will appear in one and only one set of indices.
2. This has to be done in Tensorflow, so that gradient can flow through this operation.

Do you have any idea how to perform that operation? I suspect I need to use tf.slice and probably tf.while_loop.

Comment: Can two sets of column indices have common elements? And if that is true, would every column index always be part of one of the sets? A general solution would be better, of course, but a restricted version might make it easier to solve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`tf.segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/segment_sum):

```
import tensorflow as tf

nums = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
column_idx = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Data as TF tensor
    data = tf.constant(nums)
    # Make segment ids
    segments = tf.concat([tf.tile([i], [len(lst)]) for i, lst in enumerate(column_idx)], axis=0)
    # Select columns
    data_cols = tf.gather(tf.transpose(data), tf.concat(column_idx, axis=0))
    col_sum = tf.transpose(tf.segment_sum(data_cols, segments))
    print(sess.run(col_sum))
```

Output:

```
[[ 6  9]
 [12  3]]
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot, this tf.segment_sum is the operation I was looking for and couldn't find.

Comment: @Tom I've changed it for a similar but more general solution.

Comment: To make your example work, I had to add before the last line: with tf.Session() as sess:

Answer (score -1):

I know of a crude way of solving this in NumPy if you don't mind solving this problem with NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])

grid1 = np.ix_([0], [0, 1, 2])
item1 = np.sum(mat[grid1])
grid2 = np.ix_([1], [0, 1, 2])
item2 = np.sum(mat[grid2])
grid3 = np.ix_([0], [3, 4])
item3 = np.sum(mat[grid3])
grid4 = np.ix_([1], [3, 4])
item4 = np.sum(mat[grid4])

result = np.array([[item1, item3], [item2, item4]])
```

Comment: Actually I really need to solve this in Tensorflow. Because gradient needs to flow through this operation.

Comment: Would it help to convert the NumPy array to a TensorFlow tensor according to this page: [LINK](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)?

Comment: I don't think so. Because then the link between the source elements (numpy array) and the result would still be done via numpy instead of tensorflow . This 'mat' (the name of the variable you use) is produced using tf.variable on which I am training. And the result of the aggregation is used by the tensorflow trainer.  Everything really needs to be happening in Tensorflow.